# OpenGL ES translation

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to write an Android application that can translate a triangle a have used the 
http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/motion.html code from Google but when I replaced the

```
Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, -1.0f);

Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
```

with

```
Matrix.translate(mMVPMatrix,0,dx,dy,0);
```

the triangle was moving also on the Z axis and it did not look like a translation at all

What can i do ?

Answer (score 3):

The following code:

```
Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, -1.0f);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
```

means:

```
mRotationMatrix <-- Create a rotation matrix of mAngle degrees around axis -Z
mMVPMatrix <-- The product of mRotationMatrix and mMVPMatrix
```

While the following:

```
Matrix.translate(mMVPMatrix,0,dx,dy,0);
```

means:

```
mMVPMatrix <-- Translate mMVPMatrix of dx along X axis and dy along Y axis
```

I assume that mMVPMatrix is a perspective projection (and the P of MVP usually suggests that). Usually you don't translate stuff that has already been projected. Try the following instead:

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(mTranslationMatrix, 0);
Matrix.translateM(mTranslationMatrix, 0, dx, dy, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mTranslationMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you want to translate your MVP matrix, you want to create an identity matrix, translate it, then multiply it with the `mMVPMatrix`.